# nginx route all except a few to folder

Tags: nginx, server, webserver, redirect

My nginx configuration looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name bla;

    location /api {
      include uwsgi_params;
      uwsgi_read_timeout 600;
      uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/html/site.sock;
    }

    location / {
      root /var/www/html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Basically I have a Vue front-end, and a Flask/uWSGI backend.  All the backend requests (/api) are covered by that first location rule.  All the front-end requests are covered by the second.  Works great.

What I want to do is have an exception for a handful of routes that are not prefixed with `api/` in which they are forwarded to the backend instead of the front-end.

For example, I want to be able to send `/this-is-an-api-request` to the backend, instead of being forwarded to index.html.  I can't use redirects because there are some POST requests and I haven't had any success being able to redirect those.

Comment: Have you tried simply duplicating the api location block with the other paths? location /this-is-an-api-request { same contents as api location block }

Comment: POST requests can be redirected using a `return 307`. Are there enough exceptional URIs to justify using a `map`?

Comment: 307 redirect wasn't working for for some reason.  I kept getting method not allowed for every type of request for that route.  @mjb2kmn's solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `error_page` to forward all requests which causing a 404 error to the backend ([docs](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)).

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name bla;

    location /api {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 600;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/html/site.sock;
    }

    location / {
        error_page 404 = @error;
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    location @error {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 600;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/html/site.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: That location will not generate 404 responses. See the `try_files` statement.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't noticed that, sorry. I tested it without `try_files`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Rather than using `error_page 404` you could use `try_files $uri $uri/ @error;`. But in either case, it still breaks the OPs front-end router.